# Replace spaces with tab character

Tags: c, string, replace

I just finished the first chapter of *The C Programming Language* and there are a few exercises before moving on. I already completed the one to replace the tab character with spaces which was fairly easy, but I am stuck on the one to replace space characters with the proper amount of tabs and spaces to achieve the same spacing.

My implementation "sometimes" works, so essentially it doesn't work. Here is the function:

```
#define TABLEN 5

// entab: replace consecutive spaces of length TABLEN with the tab character
void entab(char string[])
{
    int i, consec;
    int to, from, tabloc;

    consec = 0;
    for (i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        // count consecutive spaces in a string
        if (string[i] == ' ') ++consec;
        else consec = 0;

        if (consec >= TABLEN) {
            // set location to insert tab character
            tabloc = (i - TABLEN) + 1;

            for (to = tabloc, from = i;
                string[from] != '\0'; ++from, ++to)
            {
                // replace space characters
                string[to] = string[from];
            }

            string[tabloc] = '\t';
            string[to] = '\0';
            i = tabloc;
            consec = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

This function is extremely inconsistent in working successfully to the point where there isn't even a pattern of when it does and doesn't work. By "doesn't work", I mean one of two situations. 1.) the spaces are deleted and no tab character is inserted, or 2.) the spaces are deleted, a tab character is inserted, but somehow an extra space is added in. These issues have led me to realize that the problem exists in the loop that replaces the spaces, but I'm so new to C that I have no idea what is wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: I haven't looked to closely at the code but you realize that 5 spaces doesn't always mean it's replaceable by a tab, right? 3 spaces could be a tab, depending on where in the line the spaces are.

Comment: Yea I realize that, the book said to assume a fixed length so I just used the length of the tab character in my terminal

Comment: That's not what I meant. Consider this: type 'a', then four spaces, and then 'a'. Now on another line, if you typed 'a' and then tabbed with a tab size of 5, the following 'a' would be in the same spot as the one in the line above.

Comment: Actually, when I do that, the result is 'a' pushed out a full tab and an extra space

Comment: @samrap the solution I have provided is working, i think its to do with your indexes after you have found TABLEN spaces.. Compare this boundary conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how tabs work:

If you typed

```
      Tab 
      v     v     v     v
 ------------------------
|     a
|a    a
|aa   a
|aaa  a
|aaaa a
```

Notice how if there was 5, 4, 3, 2, or 1 spaces, they all could be equally represented as a tab. This is why 5 spaces doesn't equal a tab (even when the tab size is set to 5). Consider this case as well:

```
      v     v     v     v
 ------------------------
|aaaa     a
|    12345
```

But when you replace those 5 spaces with a tab, you get:

```
      v     v     v     v
 ------------------------
|aaaa a
| 12345
```

Here's an working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void Print_As_String(char * buffer, unsigned int size);
void Print_As_Hex(char * buffer, unsigned int size);

void Convert_Tab_To_Space(char * buffer, unsigned int size, unsigned int tab_size);

int main(unsigned int argc, char * argv[]){

  unsigned int i = 0;
  unsigned int arg_length = 0;

  if (argc <= 1){
    printf("Usage: \"Text with spaces\", \"More text with spaces\", etc\n");
    return -1;
  }

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++){

      arg_length = strlen(argv[i]);

      Print_As_String (argv[i], arg_length);
      Print_As_Hex    (argv[i], arg_length);

      Convert_Tab_To_Space(argv[i], arg_length, 8);

      Print_As_String (argv[i], arg_length);
      Print_As_Hex    (argv[i], arg_length);
  }

  return 0;
}

void Print_As_String(char * buffer, unsigned int size){
  printf("%.*s\n", size, buffer);
}

void Print_As_Hex(char * buffer, unsigned int size){

  unsigned int i = 0;
  const char hex_table[16] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

  for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
    unsigned char high_byte = 0;
    unsigned char low_byte = 0;

    high_byte = (buffer[i] & 0xF0) >> 4;
    low_byte  = (buffer[i] & 0x0F) >> 0;

    putc(hex_table[high_byte], stdout);
    putc(hex_table[low_byte], stdout);
    putc(' ', stdout);
  }

  putc('\n', stdout);
}

void Shift_Characters_Left(char * buffer,
                       unsigned int position_start,
                       unsigned int position_end,
                       unsigned int size);

void Convert_Tab_To_Space(char * buffer, unsigned int size, unsigned int tab_size){

  unsigned int i = 0;
  unsigned int x = 0; /* x is used
        for getting the position in
        the current line. This is
        different from 'i' because
        there may be many lines in
        one string.
  */

  for (i = 0; i < size; i++){

    if (buffer[i] == '\t'){ /* the x coordinates
      change in this fashion when a new
      tab is found.
    */
      x += tab_size - (x % tab_size);

    } else if (buffer[i] == ' '){

      unsigned int tab_remainder = 0; // how many spots are left for a tab
      unsigned int space_i = 1; // space index

      tab_remainder = (x % tab_size);

      while ((i + space_i) < size){

        /* if the space count makes up for the
           missing spots in the tab remainder,
           replaces the spaces with a tab
        */

        if ((tab_remainder + space_i) == tab_size){
          Shift_Characters_Left(buffer,      // move the spot at the end of
                                i + space_i, // the spaces to the spot at
                                i + 1,       // the start of the spaces
                                size);
          buffer[i] = '\t';
        }

        if (buffer[i + space_i] != ' '){
          i += space_i;
          break;
        }

        space_i++;
      }

    } else if (buffer[i] == '\n'){
      x = 0;
    } else {
      x++;
    }
  }
}

void Shift_Characters_Left(char * buffer,
                       unsigned int position_start,
                       unsigned int position_end,
                       unsigned int size){
  memmove(buffer + position_end,
      buffer + position_start,
      size - position_end);
  memset(&buffer[position_start], 0, (size - 1) - position_start);
}
```

But there is an unaddressable error I get when I test this problem. I think it's something i'm doing wrong with `memset` (probably an off-by-one error).

Comment: I'm not sure I'm seeing the connection here...in my program, I only insert a tab if there were 5 spaces in a row. The `consec` variable specifically checks this. Wouldn't that mean that if I move each character over until there is only one space left and replace it with a tab, it would equal the same length?

Comment: no, 5 spaces only equals a tab if they are aligned on a 5 character boundary from the beginning of the line.

Comment: so how am I supposed to approach this then, if there is no way to guarantee an amount of spaces to equal a tab?

Comment: I'm writing an annotated solution now.

Comment: It's late over here I have to get some sleep. will check your solution in the morning. thanks!

Comment: Very good, but I think I'd make an exception for a single space that happens exactly on a tab alignment :) Use separate read/write pointers, so you do not have to use memmove for every single tab.

Answer (score 2):

The following works fine. Check the differences in the indexes

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TABLEN 5
// entab: replace consecutive spaces of length TABLEN with the tab character
void entab(char string[])
{
    int i, consec;
    int to, from, tabloc;
        printf("%s\n",string);

    consec = 0;
    for (i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        // count consecutive spaces in a string
        if (string[i] == ' ') ++consec;
        else consec = 0;

        if (consec >= TABLEN) {
            // set location to insert tab character
            tabloc = (i - TABLEN) + 1;

            for (to = tabloc+1, from = i+1;
                 string[from] != '\0'; ++from, ++to)
            {
                // replace space characters
                string[to] = string[from];
            }

            string[tabloc] = '\t';
            string[to] = '\0';
            i = tabloc+1;
            consec = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("%s",string);
}
int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    char a[] = "hello     wor   l    d";
    entab(a);
    return 0;
}
```